# how could I mention sequence of figures in a research paper?

Tags: research-process, writing, graphics, cross-referencing

I want to say that:

Figure 1, 2, 3 and 4 illustrate ....

how could I mention them?
 is the above sentence correct?
 or I should say figure 1 to figure 4

Comment: If using LaTeX, use the `Cleveref` package. For example: `figures \labelcref{fig:a,fig:b,fig:c} show that...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact format should be determined by the publication in which you publish your work (assuming this is what you do). You should be able to write Figures 1-4 or alternatively Figures 1 to 4 (although the former is what I am used to seeing). If the format uses abbreviated forms then Figs 1-4 would be the format. There is no need to repeat the word figure before both numbers in a sequence.